# How do I create a CVPixelBuffer with 32RGBA format for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, rendering, framebuffer

When trying to create a 32 bits RGBA CVPixelBuffer, I constantly get errors.

Most notably error -6680 which means: "The buffer does not support the specified pixel format."

This is the code fragment:   (Width and height are specified as 256*256)

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
//                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
//                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
//                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, WIDTH,
                                      HEIGHT, kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA, (CFDictionaryRef) options, 
                                      &pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);
```

Can anyone give a hint as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to use a different pixel format.  Just because there's a constant defined for 32RGBA doesn't mean it's supported.  This tech note lists the supported formats (as of when it was written) and the functions you can use to find out what formats are currently supported:

[Technical Q&A QA1501
Core Video - Available Pixel Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1501/_index.html)

The most similar formats that are supported are 32ARGB and 32BGRA.

Comment: It's strange. Because I need this buffer format for the new CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage function. In the RosyWriter apple example they use this very format (although they obtain this buffer from the camera).

Comment: RosyWriter doesn't mention `kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA`.  In the call to `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`, it uses `GL_RGBA` as the `internalFormat` parameter, but it uses `GL_BGRA` as the `format` parameter, which "Specifies the format of the pixel data."

Comment: In fact RosyWriter uses `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` (not `...32RGBA`).

Comment: yes! it's working! Thanks so much! Staring too long at all these parameters can make you parameter blind apparently.

Comment: @robmayoff  Hi, would you plz have a glance at my issue. thx.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611593/how-to-create-cvpixelbufferref-with-nv12-data